# How to hide a div after being appended to another div in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide a div (this.elmWheel) after an ajax call is made .loadUrl().

Using this code I am not able to hide the div.
What am I doing wrong here?
I am using jquery 1.4.2

```
var Viewer = function(url) {
        var scope = this;
        this.elm = '#viewer';
        this.elmWheel = '#loader-wheel';
        this.url = url;
        this.init = function() {
            this.loadWheelInit();
            this.loadUrl();
        };
        this.loadWheelInit = function() {
            $('<div id="' + scope.elmWheel + '">Loading ...</div>').appendTo(this.elm);
        };
        this.loadWheelHide = function() {
            $(this.elmWheel).hide();
            console.log('hide');
        };
        this.loadUrl = function() {
            // simulate loading
            setTimeout(function() {
                // fetch img from api
                $.get(this.url, function(data) {
                    scope.loadWheelHide();
                    console.log('show image');
                    // add img to the dom
                    var img = $('<img id="img">');
                    img.attr('src', this.url);
                    img.appendTo(scope.elm);


                });
            }, 2000);
        };
    };



        <div id="viewer" class="">

        </div>
```

I am creating an instance with this code, image an Loadind wheel are appended correctly, just not able to hide it

```
    var viewer = new Viewer('img/1.jpg');
    viewer.init();
```

Comment: How you create a `Viewer` instance? How it's methoad are called?

Comment: var viewer = new Viewer('img/1.jpg');
        viewer.init();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you are creating a loading wheel, it gets a wrong ID.

```
this.loadWheelInit = function() {
    $('<div id="' + scope.elmWheel + '">Loading ...</div>').appendTo(this.elm);
};
```

This results in

```
<div id="#loader-wheel">Loading...</div>
```

In a `loadWheelHide` method, you are trying to access load wheel by selector `#loader-wheel`, but there are not such ID.

You need to store an ID in elmWheel

```
this.elmWheel = 'loader-wheel'
```

And prepend a hash sign when you do searching

```
this.loadWheelHide = function() {
    $('#' + this.elmWheel).hide();
    console.log('hide');
};
```

Comment: `#loader-wheel` is a CSS-selector which means "get an element which ID is equals to loader-wheel". There are many other CSS-selectors like '.' to search an elements with a specific CSS-class (`$('.myClazz')` to match `<div class='myClazz orElse'></div>`) or just tag names to search specified tags (`$('p')` to match `<p>some text</p>`). So, then you creating an element, you need not pass a selector, but then you search - you need to.